HTML form next and Submit buttons are ignoring required fields
I have a multi-pages form with required fields where these fields are ignored when I click the next or submit buttons.
I would like it to prevent going on the next page unless all the required inputs are filled.
Feel free to ask if you need more details about this.
Thanks
Here is my Javascript code for the Multi-pages and buttons behaviour:
let step = document.getElementsByClassName('step');
let prevBtn = document.getElementById('prev-btn');
let nextBtn = document.getElementById('next-btn');
let submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit-btn');
let form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
let preloader = document.getElementById('preloader-wrapper');
let bodyElement = document.querySelector('body');
let succcessDiv = document.getElementById('success');

form.onsubmit = () => {
    return false
}
let current_step = 0;
let stepCount = 3;
step[current_step].classList.add('d-block');
if (current_step == 0) {
    prevBtn.classList.add('d-none');
    submitBtn.classList.add('d-none');
    nextBtn.classList.add('d-inline-block');
}
const progress = (value) => {
    document.getElementsByClassName('progress-bar')[0].style.width = `${value}%`;
}

nextBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    current_step++;
    let previous_step = current_step - 1;
    if ((current_step > 0) && (current_step <= stepCount)) {
        prevBtn.classList.remove('d-none');
        prevBtn.classList.add('d-inline-block');
        step[current_step].classList.remove('d-none');
        step[current_step].classList.add('d-block');
        step[previous_step].classList.remove('d-block');
        step[previous_step].classList.add('d-none');
        if (current_step == stepCount) {
            submitBtn.classList.remove('d-none');
            submitBtn.classList.add('d-inline-block');
            nextBtn.classList.remove('d-inline-block');
            nextBtn.classList.add('d-none');
        }
    } else {
        if (current_step > stepCount) {
            form.onsubmit = () => {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    progress((100 / stepCount) * current_step);
});
 
 
prevBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (current_step > 0) {
        current_step--;
        let previous_step = current_step + 1;
        prevBtn.classList.add('d-none');
        prevBtn.classList.add('d-inline-block');
        step[current_step].classList.remove('d-none');
        step[current_step].classList.add('d-block')
        step[previous_step].classList.remove('d-block');
        step[previous_step].classList.add('d-none');
        if (current_step < stepCount) {
            submitBtn.classList.remove('d-inline-block');
            submitBtn.classList.add('d-none');
            nextBtn.classList.remove('d-none');
            nextBtn.classList.add('d-inline-block');
            prevBtn.classList.remove('d-none');
            prevBtn.classList.add('d-inline-block');
        }
    }
 
    if (current_step == 0) {
        prevBtn.classList.remove('d-inline-block');
        prevBtn.classList.add('d-none');
    }
    progress((100 / stepCount) * current_step);
});
 
 
submitBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    preloader.classList.add('d-block');
 
    const timer = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
 
    timer(3000)
        .then(() => {
            bodyElement.classList.add('loaded');
        }).then(() => {
            step[stepCount].classList.remove('d-block');
            step[stepCount].classList.add('d-none');
            prevBtn.classList.remove('d-inline-block');
            prevBtn.classList.add('d-none');
            submitBtn.classList.remove('d-inline-block');
            submitBtn.classList.add('d-none');
            succcessDiv.classList.remove('d-none');
            succcessDiv.classList.add('d-block');
        })
 
});

Here is the HTML code for the buttons :
<div id="q-box__buttons">
  <button id="prev-btn" type="button">Previous</button> 
  <button id="next-btn" type="button">Next</button> 
  <button id="submit-btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>

Some required input example :
<div class="mt-2">
  <label class="form-label">First Name :</label> 
  <input class="form-control" id="fName" name="fName" type="text" required autocomplete="off">
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
    Please provide a First Name !
    </div>
</div>


where is your form?

@André my form is really huge but I'll update my initial post to include some of the required fields I'm talking about

Aren't you using the <form> tag?

Can you edit your question and convert your code into a reproducible snippet?

@André yes I am
